# Split single-review.php to two parts

Tags: functions

I have a created a new page template which I want to use for my custom post types as well.

I need to retain the existing format of my old custom post types but for any new custom post types, I want to implement my new page template.

What is the best way of doing this?

I thought about using a custom field and if it exists, then the new page template should be loaded, else load the normal `single-review.php` code.

I have come up with the conditional statement for the custom field but I don't know where to proceed from here.

```
<?php $myurl = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'newstuff', true); if($myurl) { ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use an if statement, inside your post loop do something like this:

```
while ( have_posts() {
    the_post();
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'metakey', true );
    if ( $value == 'a' ) {
        get_template_part( 'something' );
    } else {
        get_template_part( 'somethingelse');
    }
}
```

If I were to take your question more literally however, I might interpret it as:

> WordPress loads `single-review.php` when I load my review post, but i want it to load a different file instead if a custom meta has a certain value.

To which there is an answer that would let you do that. But it's massive overkill for what you're trying to do, and digging a hole for yourself, especially when such a simple basic alternative exists. I think you have to question why it is that you need to choose a completely different template based on a custom meta, or if it's the entire template that needs changing

Comment: thanks Tom, but I am confused by your answer. I need to retain the old format for my existing posts and start using the new format for any future posts. The custom field idea was my way of doing this.. Are you saying I could this in a better way? If so, please let me know!

Comment: My answer uses custom fields ( it may save yourself some confusion going forward to always refer to them as post meta, not custom fields )

Comment: What prevents you from using the new format for all posts? You really should have mentioned your new/old format issue in your question. What other vital information have you left out? Any and all context, no matter how relevant or irrelevant you think it is would be useful

Comment: ok, I have changed the wording of the question. The most important thing is to keep the old format for existing custom post types and start using the new page template for new custom post types. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: also, I don't think your code is what I want. I want to have a completely separated template from header to footer..

Comment: then put your header and footer inside the if statement too. If checking the post meta and loading a second file is all the template does, how is it different to what you're asking?

Comment: I am confused with the syntax. Why shouldn't I be using 'require_once' instead of 'get_template_part'? The page template is located within the main theme folder whereas the single review is within the inc folder. Are you saying my single-review.php should have just the code above? And where you say something, you mean to just put the path to the page template and the old single-review ?

Comment: Shouldn't all this be happening before the loop? as I am loading a different header (js/css)...

Comment: Then you'd need to grab the post variable outside of the loop etc, you should look up `get_template_part`, `require_once` doesn't let you override things with child themes

Comment: The first thing the codex says is that I cannot load header and footer with get_template_part from my understanding?

Comment: No it means you should load the header and footer with `get_header()` and `get_footer()`, not `get_template_part('header');` etc

Comment: It might be better to ask a question about `get_template_part` rather than asking new questions in the comments

Comment: ok I have to sleep on it.. maybe I should have used a function instead to hijack the hierarchy of single-review